# How to ensure real-time data consistency in s3 to snowpipe

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds, aws-dms

S3 on RDS with DMS
And I'm going to stream load data into snowflake using S3 to snowpipe
How do I ensure data integrity?

Passing data (csv,parquet) from RDS to S3 through DMS leaves Update,insert,delete history data.
Snowflake is trying to load the data into the temp table via snowpipe and merge into the original table to load the data streaming.
But the problem here is
A new file (csv, parquet) is created every time a DML occurs on the RDS
If a large amount of DML is generated within a minute, a lot of new files are created, and I think snowpipe cannot guarantee the order, so there is a risk of inconsistency.
In other words, if a large number of files are loaded at once and the Copyinto statement is not guaranteed in order, it is expected that the data will not be consistent.
How can I resolve this issue?